# Composition of compact convergent sequence is compact convergent

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $D\in \mathbb{C}$ be open, and let $f,f_1,f_2,...:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be functions.
>
> We say the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is compactly convergent to $f$ (equivalent to locally uniformly convergent), if for each compact set $K\subset D$, the sequence $\{f_{n\restriction{K}}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $f_{\restriction{K}}$ uniformly on $K$
>
> Prove if $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge to $f$ and $g$ compactly on $D$ respectively, where $f_n$ and $g_n$ are a continuous sequence of functions, then the sequences $\{f_n+g_n\}$ and $\{f_ng_n\}$ converge to $f+g$ and $fg$ compactly on D, respectively.
>
> More so, suppose $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$ are sequences of continuous functions on open sets $S_1\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $S_2\subset \mathbb{C}$ with $g_n(S_2)\subset S_1$. Show if $f_n$ and $g_n$ converge compactly to $f$ and $g$ on $S_1$ and $S_2$ respectively, then their composition converges compactly to $f\circ g$ on $S_2$

I apologize for the multiple questions, but I believe I have proved the sum and product claims, and would appreciate if someone could look over my proof.

Since $f_n$ converges compactly on $D$ to $f$, that implies $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N_1\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall n\geq N_1$, we have $|f_{n\restriction{K}}(z)-f_{\restriction{K}}(z)|<\frac {\epsilon}{2}$ $\forall z\in K$

Likewise, since $g_n$ converges compactly on $D$ to $g$, that implies $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N_2\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall n\geq N_2$, we have $|g_{n\restriction{K}}(z)-g_{\restriction{K}}(z)|<\frac {\epsilon}{2}$ $\forall z\in K$

Now take $N=max\{N_1,N_2\}$

Then $\forall n\geq N$ and $\forall z\in K$, we see:

$|f_{n\restriction{K}}(z)+g_{n\restriction{K}}(z)-(f_{\restriction{K}}(z)+g_{\restriction{K}}(z))|\leq |f_{n\restriction{K}}(z)-f_{\restriction{K}}(z)|+|g_{n\restriction{K}}(z)-g_{\restriction{K}}(z)|<\epsilon$

Thus $f_n+g_n$ converge compactly to $f+g$

Now for $f_ng_n$, we note that since $g_n$ converges compactly on $D$ to $g$, it is bounded on every compact set $K$. Choose B to be the maximum of all such bounds.

Then $|f_{n\restriction{N}}(z)g_{n\restriction{K}}(z)-f_{\restriction{K}}(z)g_{\restriction{K}}(z)|\leq|f_{n\restriction{K}}(z)-f_{\restriction{K}}(z)||g_{n\restriction{K}}(z)|+|g_{n\restriction{K}}(z)-g_{\restriction{K}}(z)||f_{\restriction{K}}(z)|<\frac {\epsilon}{2}B+\frac {\epsilon}{2}f_{\restriction{K}}(z)<\epsilon$

Thus $f_ng_n$ converge compactly to $fg$ on $D$.

I am not sure how to go about the composition part, and would appreciate any help. Also I would appreciate if someone could proof read my above proofs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint for showing that the composition converges uniformly on compact sets: if $K \subset S_2$ is compact the there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\{z:d(z,g(K)) \leq \delta\} \subset S_1$ because $g(K)$ is a compact subset if $S_1$. [Here $d(z,g(K))$ stands for $\inf \{|z-w|:w \in g(K)\}$]. Note that  $\{z:d(z,g(K)) \leq \delta\}$ is a compact set. There exists $m$ such that for all $n \geq m$, $g_n(K)$ is contained in this compact set. (Use uniform convergence to prove this).  Now use the fact that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\{z:d(z,g(K)) \leq \delta\}$

Comment: Note that this proof does not hold if $g$ maps $S_2$ to a point in the boundary of $S_1$ and $f_n$ is not defined or divergent at that point. The condition $g_n(S_2) \subset S_1$ should be replaced by $g(S_2) \subset S_1$ to rule out this case.